# Is there a specification for glob patterns?

Tags: java, glob

While searching a bug (not matched filenames for the pattern *.{ABC,XYZ}) in a java program, i found out that org.apache.oro.text.GlobCompiler.globToPerl5(...) has incomplete support of glob expressions ([tcl tk doc of glob](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm)).

By reading the implemented code in the SVN svn.Apache.org , it showed that globpatterns like *.{ABC,XYZ} are not handled.

I told this a colleague and he stated that the "{" "}" are not part of Glob, but might be handled by the shell.

Some Websites(like tcl/tk and [link taken from glob article wikipedia](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/globbingref.html)) mention the curly braces, others not (like Wikipedia:[glob on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))), i would like to know if they are standard, and therefore: is there a unique source of truth, a specification of glob Patterns?

Regards
dj

Comment: This may depend on the OS, the file system, and the shell. You may be best off by defining your own globbing and document what will match how to your users.

Comment: You might want to use Java’s own glob-capable [PathMatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-).  Usually the [Files.newDirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-) convenience method is easier than using a PathMatcher directly.  It isn’t a standard, but at least it’s well defined and stable.  And it supports `{`…`}` expressions.